# How to solve this bit operation?

Tags: c#, .net, logic, bit-manipulation

I have one byte in with I need to replace last (least important) bits.
Example below.

```
Original byte:      xxxx0110
Replacement byte:       1111
What I want to get: xxxx1111
```

---

```
Original byte:      xxxx1111
Replacement byte:       0000
What I want to get: xxxx0000
```

---

```
Original byte:      xxxx0000
Replacement byte:       1111
What I want to get: xxxx1111
```

---

```
Original byte:      xxxx1010
Replacement byte:       1111
What I want to get: xxxx1111
```

---

```
Original byte:      xxxx0101
Replacement byte:       0111
What I want to get: xxxx0111
```

Comment: You have a replacement nibble :).

Comment: As usual: what have you tried already?

Comment: value = (original & 240) | (replacement & 15) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 value = (byte)( (value & ~15) | newByte);
```

The `~15` creates a mask of everything **except** the last 4 bits; `value & {that mask}` takes the last 4 bits away, then `| newByte` puts the bits from the new data in their place.

Comment: In what scenario? What is the **full** value of `newByte`? In the sample data you only show 4 bits, so my *assumption* is that others are 0. If not, just replace `newByte` with `(newByte & 15)`

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with a combination of bitwise AND to clear the bits and bitwise OR to set the bits.

To clear the lowest four bits, you can AND with a value that is 1 everywhere except at those bits, where it's zero.  One value like this would be `~0xF`, which is the complement of `0xF`, which is four ones: `0b1111`.

To set the bits, you can then use bitwise OR with the bits to set.  Since `0 OR x = x`, this works as you'd intend it.

The net result would be

```
(x & ~0xF) | bits
```

EDIT: As per Eamon Nerbonne's comment, you should then cast back to a `byte`:

```
(byte)((x & ~0xF) | bits)
```

Comment: +1, but note that bitwise operators in C# implicitly convert to `int` - to avoid confusion, you should probably cast the entire expression as Marc does.

Comment: @Eamon Nerbonne- Thanks for pointing this out!  I'm not much of a C# programmer, and it's good to get that sort of feedback.  Original post should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is right, you want to OR your byte (after left shift 4 times) with the replacement byte(left shift 4 times, too). Then right shift 4 times and you will get the desired result.

For example: a = 1001 1101
Replacement byte: 0000 1011

Left shift a 4 times: 1101 0000
Left shift replacement 4 times: 1011 0000

OR result: 1111

Right shift 4 times: 1011 (end result).

Maybe this link is helpful: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/leftrightshift.aspx

Answer (score -1):

`trim` the last 4 bits. and `append` the new ones.